# PHPunit: testing a Repository

Tags: unit-testing, laravel, phpunit, mockery

I am testing my repository in Laravel and I came across a few issues, most probably with regards to the structure of my methods.

So, my repository looks like:

```
<?php

namespace Repositories\User;

use App\Test\Models\Entities\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserRepository implements UserInterface
{

    /**
     * @var Model $userModel
     */
    protected $userModel;

    /**
     * Setting our class $userModel to the injected model
     *
     * @param Model $userModel
     * @return UserRepository
     */
    public function __construct(Model $userModel)
    {
        $this->userModel = $userModel;
    }


    /**
     * Returns the User object associated with the userEmail
     *
     * @param string $userEmail
     * @return User | null
     */
    public function getUserByEmail($userEmail)
    {
        // Search by email
        $user = $this->userModel
                        ->where('email', '=', strtolower($userEmail))
                        ->first();

        if ($user) {
            return $user->first();
        }

        return null;
    }



}


 /**
     * @param $id
     * @param $email
     * @param $source
     *
     * @dataProvider usersDataProvider
     */
    public function testGetUserByEmail($id, $email, $source)
    {
        $user = new User();
        $user->id = $id;
        $user->email = $email;
        $user->user_source_id = $source;

        $this->user->shouldReceive('getUserByEmail')->once()
            ->andReturn($user);

    }
```

I am quite new working with Mockery and am just wondering whether I am following the correct approach in order to test my `getUserByEmail($email)` method. Please bare in mind that (as expected) `getUserByEmail($email)` makes a call to the Database.

Also, this is the message that I receive:

`PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function connection() on null in /private/var/www/ff-php-prelaunch/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php`, which probably implies that there is no initialized connection to the DB.

**UPDATE**

Btw, my `setUp()` is as follows:

```
  public function setUp()
    {
        $this->user = Mockery::mock('App\Test\Models\Entities\User');

        parent::setUp();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't extend the default `TestCase` class provided by Laravel in the `tests` directory. Your environment is not correct and you have no connection to the database.

If you don't want to actually query the database you should use `Mockery` to create a mock of your dependencies (here $userModel). You basically create a Mock the following way, I didn't test this code but the general idea is here.

```
protected function setUp() {
    parent::setUp();

    $userModelMockedMethods = [
        'where' => 'some return'
    ];
    // This is our dependency mock
    $userModelMock = Mockery::mock(Model::class, $userModelMockedMethods);
    // this mock now will return 'some return' if you call the `where` method 
    // on it. If you wish the where method to return something callable, you
    // should return another mock instead of a string

    // This replaces the mock in the dependency manager.
    $this->app->instance(Model::class, $UserModelMock);
}
```

Comment: That is correct because I am extending from `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase`. However, in this case I have to add `createApplication()`, which is required by default.

Comment: If you look at the default TestCase it has a createApplication but doesn't derive from PHPUnit's TestCase but from a Laravel class.

Comment: I appreciate your tips, @AsTeR. But then, what am I going to assert in my test if I mock the methods? I am a bit confused at this point, to be honest.

Comment: @thitami Normally unit tests are meant to isolate the tested component from the rest. I have never ran in a case where I was to mock the database, because it's a hassle and I don't really get the added value. On that concrete case I suggest to NOT do it, but since you asked the question, the way to do it was in the answer.

Comment: Ok, great. I will follow your advice to not test again the db data. I have refactored my code a little bit and particularly `setUp()`. However, I am now receiving: `Fatal error: Call to a member function instance() on null`. Any thoughts?

Comment: My advice was to test against the db data. For your problem, I would bet that you haven't called the `parent::setUp()`

Comment: `public function setUp()
    {
       parent::setUp();
       $userModelMockedMethods = [
           'where' => 'some return' 
       ];

       $this->userModelMock = Mockery::mock('App\Test\Models\Entities\User' $userModelMockedMethods);
        $this->app->instance(User::class, $this->userModelMock);
    }`
This is my `setUp()` right now.

Comment: Got an update:  `App::instance(Subscriber::class, $this->subscriberModelMock);` should be used instead of ` $this->app->instance(Subscriber::class, $this->subscriberModelMock);`
is not declared somewhere. Now getting: `RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set.`, which means that I got over the previous issue.